Qt Virtual Keyboard Not Appearing in linux X11 without Windows Manager
I'm developing an application that uses Qt Virtual Keyboard and is designed to run in an environment without a window manager. I launch it with the command startx ./app.

On my development workstation, the virtual keyboard displays perfectly. When I select an EditLine field, the keyboard appears as expected.
When I SSH into the target device from my workstation with X forwarding, the keyboard also appears when I focus on a TextEdit.
Running the application directly on my workstation from a terminal with startx ./app also shows the virtual keyboard.
My first line in main() function is : qputenv("QT_IM_MODULE", QByteArray("qtvirtualkeyboard"));
I'm using Qt 6.8 (c++ no qt quick or qml) platform xcb.

However, when I run the application on the final target environment and select a QLineEdit, neither the keyboard nor the cursor appear. But the focus is there, if I press a real key it's added to the QLineEdit.
Clues are welcome!
Update:
If, in the target, I start the X11 with gnome and then start the app, the virtual keyboard appears. but if I start directly with startx ./app doesn't...
Update#2: I can open it if I open a very simple openbox WM only running that app.

Yes, you need a window manager to manage more than one window.

X11 is not just Linux and surely not a Linux-specific API, so I removed that tag.

From your description, it's not clear what exactly you are doing and where. "from a terminal" means one of the terminals that are not inside an existing X11 GUI session, not a terminal window like xterm, right?

@UlrichEckhardt when I talk about my workstation what I do is start a virtual terminal alt-F2 and type on it startx ./app. it starts a new X11 server and it works. But is true that there is another X server running in VT#1

@Botje depends... I can open dialogs from my main window without problem. Also I believe that some time ago I've open X app from standalone app running in on X
